# karma-browserify fails with bundle() no longer accepts options arguments

Tags: karma-runner, browserify

When I run my karma unit tests I get the following error:

```
karma start karma.conf.js 

Fatal error: bundle() no longer accepts option arguments
Move all option arguments to the browserify() constructor.
```

I am running using the following versions:

```
karma 0.12.21
karma-browserify 0.2.1
browserify 5.9.3
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that the karma-browserify version 0.2.1 - currently the latest version - is not compatible with the 5.0.0 release of browserify on Jul 22, 2014.

The package.json in karma-browserify does not prevent the 5.0.0 or greater version of browserify to be installed on an npm install, so when you install a new project or update your browserify version you will get this error.

until karma-browserify is updated you can force your project to use the most recent 4.X version of browserify - which is compatible with karma-browserify - version 4.2.3 via adding the following line to package.json:

```
"browserify" : "^4.0.0"
```

then running:

```
npm update browserify
```